# C# .Net class library database schema create

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

Im creating a class library that will be used in several projects.  This library includes a handfull of entities with associated tables in the database.  My question is: how do I create these tables when I include this library in a project?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking.  Adding a reference to a project doesn't include setting up a database schema.  Perhaps you could do something through NuGet, but I'm not sure.  You may also want to look into EF Code First - [here's one tutorial](http://codefirst.codeplex.com/) that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want a library of objects that are used to generate a database?

If so you can achieve this with EntityFramework CodeFirst.

At minimum you'll need your objects and a DbContext.

a typical set up maybe as follows:

**Entities**

```
public class Person {

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class MyDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {

     public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)

     public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

These would live in your project and when you add a reference to it, for example a web project. There are different ways to build the Database, you could call the constructor (MyDbContext) from your web project and pass a connection string to a server.